# how to manage costs of Snowflake Cloud test environnement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cloud

we have Poc ed Snowflake Cloud environement and I'm thinking about test costs.
we use ODI to run ELT queries, in dev/test phase, some queries could be wrong because of missing join or some thing else (dev environment exists for such things)
Comparing to traditional way, some times I keep running many packages the night, then, the morning when I go work I check results to see if something was wrong, if row number is what I expect etc, there is no impact, no extra charge of what I did on my company fees.
but if I do so with snowflake, If I come to work the morning and my boss tells me what you did yesterday ? we got 30000 dollars bill for yesterday tests running all the night, I'll be in a very bad situation.
the same question may be asked with novice developers
So how to deal with tests costs in cloud environment?
please consider ELT cases with a database/datawarehouse and a lot of data exchange and computing resources.
I read article below but there is no concrete idea.
https://hystax.com/how-test-environment-management-helps-achieve-cloud-cost-optimization-goals/
thank you.

Comment: Set a resource monitor on the account and every warehouse individually.

Comment: It’s a different mindset. If you’re not being billed for what you are running you can run what you want (though that’s still not a good idea) - basically a “throw everything at the wall and see what sticks” approach. If what you run actually has a demonstrable cost then you need to think more about what you are running and why, do proper testing upfront, etc

Comment: It seems like you need something that would run overnight(for 6/7hours) and prepare data overnight. You can use smallest warehouse (XSmall) which costs max 6/7credits. Considering $2 per credit you can assume $14. Add storage cost $30/TB. Adding buffer, it may go like $15 to $30 daily. Monthly around $1000 just for your process. Now if you have large data crunching requirement, you can multiply it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.  The answer is so complex it needs an article - so I will write one.

Update:  Here's the article:
https://www.analytics.today/blog/top-10-strategies-for-snowflake-cost-optimization

Meanwhile, run queries on a DEV_BATCH warehouse built using the following code:

```
use role accountadmin;
create or replace resource monitor dev_batch_wh_mon with
   credit_quota = 40 -- 10 hours on a MEDIUM size warehouse
   triggers on 80 percent  do notify
            on 100 percent do suspend
            on 110 percent do suspend_immediate;

create or replace warehouse dev_batch with
   warehouse_size = 'MEDIUM'
   auto_suspend   = 30
   auto_resume    = true
   initially_suspended = true
   resource_monitor = dev_batch_wh_mon
   enable_query_acceleration = false
   min_cluster_count = 1
   max_cluster_count = 2
   scaling_policy    = 'ECONOMY'
   statement_timeout_in_seconds = 10800;   -- 10,800 = 3 hours
```

This has the following purpose:

1. The resource monitor limits spend on the warehouse to X credits per day
2. The warehouse will auto-suspend if there's no queries executing within 30 seconds.  Yes, that is a sensible setting.  I will explain in the article.
3. The warehouse is linked to the resource monitor - to avoid a massive over-spend
4. Query Acceleration Service is switched off - meaning you won't use additional resources to complete very long running tasks
5. MIN_CLUSTER_COUNT set to 1 - means you won't spin up a huge number of warehouses and keep them running
6. MAX_CLUSTER_COUNT = 2 - means you limit the ability to scale out if you run a huge number of concurrent queries
7. SCALING_POLICY = ECONOMY - means you will keep the warehouse busy before scaling out - at least 6 minutes of work queued
8. STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS sets the maximum time for any given SQL statement to execute. 10,800 means any single SQL statement running for more than three hours will be automatically killed.
9. The warehouse size is set to MEDIUM which means it will burn 4 Credits per hour (or 8 credits per hour based upon a MAX_CLUSTER_COUNT = 2 if there's enough concurrent queries submitted).

Finally, I would make sure any batch queries are executed concurrently on different sessions to make sure the warehouse is fully loaded over-night.  Running them sequentially will be potentially very inefficient as the warehouse will be under-utilized.

Once I've published the article on [www.Analytics.Today](http://www.Analytics.Today) I will update this answer to link to it.

**What NOT to do**

I spent 5 years as Solution Architect at Snowflake.  The most daft thing I encountered was...

```
create or replace warehouse test_wh with
   warehouse_size = 'X4LARGE'
   auto_suspend   = 0
   auto_resume    = true
   min_cluster_count = 8
   max_cluster_count = 10
```

This burned around $120,000 before anyone realised.  The offending person was not fired but eventually left the company.

Hope this helps,
John Ryan